# Segfault in parallel quicksort partition

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, quicksort

I am trying to write a parallelized quicksort partition, but somehow, I am getting a segfault.

Here is how I'm doing it:

```
unsigned int NumList:: partition_par(vector<int>& keys, unsigned int low,
                                     unsigned int high)
{
    // Use the last element as the pivot
    int pivot = keys[high];

    unsigned int n = high - low + 1;
    if(n == 1) {
        return low;
    }
    int tmp[n-1];
    unsigned int lt[n-1]; // lt array used to add elements less than the pivot
    unsigned int gt[n-1]; // gt array used to add elements greater than the pivot

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= n-1; i++) {
        tmp[i] = keys[low + i];
        if(tmp[i] < pivot) {
                lt[i] = 1;
        }
        else {
                lt[i] = 0;
        }
        if(tmp[i] > pivot) {
                gt[i] = 1;
        }
        else {
                gt[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= n-1; i++) {
        lt[i] = lt[i] + lt[i-1];
        gt[i] = gt[i] + gt[i-1];
    }
    unsigned int k = low + lt[n-1]; // get position of the pivot
    keys[k] = pivot;

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= n-1; i++) {
        if(tmp[i] < pivot) {
                keys[low + lt[i] - 1] = tmp[i];
        }
        else if(tmp[i] > pivot) {
                keys[k + gt[i]] = tmp[i];
        }
    }

    return k;
}
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this segfault. I tried debugging it, but I still can't seem to find the problem. What needs to be fixed here?

Comment: Save yourself a bit of "Hmmmmm?" and replace `i <= n-1` with `i < n`

Comment: How big is `n`? You could be blowing off the end of the stack.

Comment: `int tmp[n-1];` -- This  and lines that look like this are not legal C++.  You're using `std::vector`, so you should be using it here also, i.e. `std::vector<int> tmp(n-1);`

Answer (score 1):

Your `tmp`, `lt` and `gt` arrays are not long enough.  The last element you access in your loops is `n-1`, so the arrays need to be of size `n`, not `n - 1`.

Using `std::vector` (instead of the non-standard Variable Length Array) can avoid other problems (like a stack overflow if `n` is too large), and could detect this problem if indexing using `at`.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code to look like this:

```
unsigned int NumList:: partition_par(vector<int>& keys, unsigned int low, unsigned int high)
{
    // Use the last element as the pivot
    int pivot = keys[high];

    unsigned int n = high - low + 1;
    if(n == 1) {
        return low;
    }

    int* tmp = new int[n];
    unsigned int* lt = new unsigned int[n];  // lt array used to add elements less than the pivot
    unsigned int* gt = new unsigned int[n];  // gt array used to add elements greater than the pivot
    unsigned int* prefix_lt = new unsigned int[n];
    unsigned int* prefix_gt = new unsigned int[n];

    // creates the lt and gt arrays
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        tmp[i] = keys[low + i];
        if(tmp[i] < pivot) {
                lt[i] = 1;
                gt[i] = 0;
        }
        else if(tmp[i] > pivot) {
                lt[i] = 0;
                gt[i] = 1;
        }
        else {
                lt[i] = 0;
                gt[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    prefix_lt[0] = lt[0];
    prefix_gt[0] = gt[0];

    // Uses prefix sum algorithm to get the proper positions of each element
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        prefix_lt[i] = prefix_lt[i-1] + lt[i];
        prefix_gt[i] = prefix_gt[i-1] + gt[i];
    }

    unsigned int k = low + prefix_lt[n-1]; // get position of the pivot
    keys[k] = pivot;

    // Copies each element to the correct position
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(tmp[i] < pivot) {
                keys[low + prefix_lt[i] - 1] = tmp[i];
        }
        else if(tmp[i] > pivot) {
                keys[k + prefix_gt[i]] = tmp[i];
        }
    }

    return k;
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to sort the elements properly. It seems to be putting some of the elements in the wrong indices (i.e., puts some numbers one index behind of its desired index). What seems to be the problem here?